# Subseting dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Say I have a dataframe `ARAP` with columns called `CoCd` and `VendorNo`.
I want to subset into another dataframe called `EMIU_EMIJ` all lines for combinations of:

```
CoCd="EMIJ" & VendorNo = "100010" or
CoCd="EMIU" & VendorNo = "2000001" or
CoCd="EMIU" & VendorNo = "2000006".
```

How do I combine & and | to select the lines where both combinations are met ?
I.e. it needs to pair the `CoCd` and `VendorNo` combinations together.

I tried

```
EMIU_EMIJ<-subset(ARAP,CoCd=="EMIJ"&VendorNo=="100010"|
CoCd=="EMIU"&VendorNo=="2000001"|
CoCd=="EMIU"&VendorNo=="2000006")
```

I also tried brackets

```
EMIU_EMIJ<-subset(ARAP, (CoCd=="EMIJ"&VendorNo=="100010")|(CoCd=="EMIU"&VendorNo=="2000001")|(CoCd=="EMIU"&VendorNo=="2000006"))
```

But this created an error:`"Error: unexpected symbol in:"EMIU_EMIJ"`

How do I subset for 1 of the 3 combinations mentioned above ?

Comment: Your question is inconsistent - you say, that you have dataframe EMIU_EMIJ, but you subset from object ARAP. The condition in the last line is correct and the error points to another error. Could you post full error and also sample data (use i.e. `dput`)

Comment: For a more accurate answer, update your question as Zbynek mentionned. You're probably looking for the function `extract` of the `base` package: see the Warning from the `subset` documentation.

Comment: Zbynek, you are correct, I am subsetting the DF called ARAP to create a DF called EMIU_EMIJ. Thank you, D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple `merge` with `all.y` option will do.

for example if mydf is your data

```
set.seed(111)
mydf <- data.frame(id=rep(LETTERS, each=4)[1:100], replicate(3, sample(1001, 100)),Class=sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, TRUE))
mydf$CoCd <- paste0("EMI",mydf$id)
mydf$VendorNo <- paste0(mydf$X1,mydf$X2)
mydf <- unique(mydf[,c("CoCd","VendorNo","Class","X3")])
```

and looks like this

```
    CoCd VendorNo Class   X3
1   EMIA   594577   Yes  727
2   EMIA   727137   Yes  921
3   EMIA   371939   Yes  123
4   EMIA   514176    No  950
5   EMIB   377818   Yes  668
6   EMIB    41713    No   85
7   EMIB    11637    No  579
8   EMIB   530266    No  212
9   EMIC   430566   Yes  241
10  EMIC    93958    No  533
11  EMIC   551197   Yes  176
12  EMIC   585686    No  565
13  EMID    67827   Yes  154
14  EMID    47894    No  469
15  EMID   155952    No  718
16  EMID   441649    No  835
17  EMIE   169541   Yes  945
18  EMIE   952871   Yes  452
19  EMIE   306441    No  358
20  EMIE   604730    No  920
21  EMIF   423407    No  868
22  EMIF   280668   Yes  658
23  EMIF   335907   Yes  830
24  EMIF   379620   Yes  841
25  EMIG   946644    No  471
```

and you want the combinations

```
combination_to_select<-data.frame(CoCd=c("EMIA","EMID","EMIF"),VendorNo=c('594577','47894','423407'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
combination_to_select

  CoCd VendorNo
1 EMIA   594577
2 EMID    47894
3 EMIF   423407
```

the following code gives you the subset

```
subset <- merge(mydf,combination_to_select,by=c("CoCd","VendorNo"),all.y=TRUE)
  CoCd VendorNo Class  X3
1 EMIA   594577   Yes 727
2 EMID    47894    No 469
3 EMIF   423407    No 868
```

Comment: Thanks Rfan, "plus 1" ! D